# Finding the base of trapezoid using diagonals and the angle between them. diagonals length 6 and 8, the angle is 90 degrees.

Tags: geometry

***Find the large base of trapezoid, with diagonals length 6 and 8, if the angle between them is 90 degrees.***
Actually the original problem asks to find the length of the line parallel to the base, that goes through the intersection points of the diagonals. I calculated the expression in terms of 2 bases (the harmonic ratio of trapezoid), i have also calculated (a+b), where a and b are the bases. But i need to find a*b.

Comment: A couple of sketches will show that knowing that the diagonals have length $6$ and $8$ and meet at right angles is not sufficient to determine the larger (or smaller) base.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having a hard time is that the question you ask has multiple answers. That is, the lengths of two orthogonal diagonals in a trapezoid do not determine the lengths of the bases.

For example, let the diagonals $AB$ and $CD$ be two lines of length $6$ and $8$ respectively, meeting at a point which is $1$ away from $A$ and $\frac{4}{3}$ away from $C$.  Then the length of base $BD$ is $\frac{25}{3}$.

Now let the two diagonals meet at a point which is $3$ away from $A$ and $4$ away from $C$.  Then the length of base $BD$ is $5$.